# Bootstrap Checbox Modal Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap modal checkbox not working when checkbox is checked.

The condition is when user click the checkbox the bootstrap modal popup should be displayed

Bootstrap Version 3.3.6

Jquery Version 2.1.3

```js
$(function()
{
  $('#tos-checkbox').click(function()
        {
            if ($('#tos-checkbox').is(":checked")) {
                $('#tosmodal').modal('show');
            }else {
                $('#tosmodal').modal('hide');
            }
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

<input id="tos-checkbox" type="checkbox"> 
          <span>I agree to the Terms And Conditions.</span>
                    
 <div class="modal fade" id="tosmodal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" >&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button"  class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" >Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**change ther order of JQuery. Put JQuery to very first**

```js
$(function()
{
  $('#tos-checkbox').click(function()
        {
            if ($('#tos-checkbox').is(":checked")) {
                $('#tosmodal').modal('show');
            }else {
                $('#tosmodal').modal('hide');
            }
        });
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

   

<input id="tos-checkbox" type="checkbox"> 
          <span>I agree to the Terms And Conditions.</span>
                    
 <div class="modal fade" id="tosmodal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" >&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button"  class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" >Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

JQUERY is required to use bootstrap.js. The reason why you need to rearrange the order you call bootstrap and jquery is that *you need to call jquery first* before bootstrap.js. Your question's been answered. I just want to take part in explaining. Hope it helps.